# Reload page says that the page does not exist netlify

Tags: firebase, vue.js, netlify

I have a website which contains kind of blog pages where people can post issues and other people can comment on them.

But when i go to an issue route it gets the data from firebase when the route is the same as the saved slug in the database (not a really good way to do it like this). The data is displayed to the browser but there is one major issue if you reload the page netlify says the page could not be found.

I am loading the data from `mounted()` lifecycle it might be better to do this on `asyncdata()`

Here is my code:

```
mounted() {
        self = this;
        const issues = firebase.database().ref('Issues/')
        issues.once('value', function(snapshot){ 
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                const data = childSnapshot.exportVal()
                if(self.$nuxt.$route.path == "/Issues/"+data.Slug || self.$nuxt.$route.path ==  "/issues/"+data.Slug ) {
                    self.allIssuetitels.push(data.Titel)
                    self.allIssueonderwerpen.push(data.Onderwerp)
                    self.allteksten.push(data.Tekst)
                    self.user = data.User
                    self.profielfoto = data.Profielfoto
                    self.Slug = data.Slug
                }
            })
        })
        const reacties = firebase.database().ref('/Reacties')
        reacties.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                const data = childSnapshot.exportVal()
                if(self.$nuxt.$route.path == '/Issues/'+data.Slug || self.$nuxt.$route.path == '/issues/'+data.Slug) {
                    self.reaprofielfoto.push(data.Profielfoto)
                    self.reauser.push(data.User)
                    self.allreacties.push(data.Reactie)
                }
            })
        })
    },
```

When i test it local it doesn't give me the page not found error. Is there any way of fixing this issue?

Here is where it does not work:
https://angry-lalande-a5e5eb.netlify.app/issues/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this where you are enabling users to create new pages and to have lots of user-generated content that is frequently update, you'd be well-served to look into server-side rendering.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html

I'd suggest, if you want to do that, you should migrate over to Nuxt as it makes things like this much easier.

However, there are quite a few caveats with going SSR - notably you'll need to run and manage a server.

If you don't want to look into SSR, you could use dynamic routes [as shown here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { path: '/issue/:id', component: Issue }
  ]
})
```

You could then have the `Issue` component display a skeleton loader or another loading indicator while the content is fetching.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/skeleton-loaders/

Comment: Thank you @Jordan i will take a look into it. And this will solve my issue hopefully!